# Django DRF - How can i retrive an object if i have only the foreign keys but not the pk with RetriveAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models (one is a custom user model) with a relation ManyToMany through a third model. I have the pks of the two first models in the client side and i need to retrive the relationship model object with a RetriveAPIView. How can i do it? Here is the code i got:

models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    rut = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userAccount = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.UserAccount', through='therapy.Therapy')

class Therapy(models.Model):
    patient= models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userAccount = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

views.py

```
class UpdateRetriveTherapyView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Therapy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TherapySerializer
```

urls.py (project urls)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/patient/', include('apps.patient.urls')),
    path('api/therapy/', include('apps.therapy.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

therapy.urls.py (the relationship model urls)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>', UpdateTerapiaView.as_view()),
]
```

may be there is a way to pass fk as a parameter in the url but idk.

Comment: I'ts not clear what are you trying to accomplish. Give an example of what you have and what you want to retrieve

Comment: I am not sure about your specific question, but if you want to handle custom way to pass multiple foreign key of parent model and fetch child model then use APIViews instead of RetrieveAPIViews. You can handle your all scenarios according to the requirement.